# Javascript - Access multiple nested elements with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to get some values of a website using a Chrome Function i am working on. I am able to fetch the first `listing-name` using `document.querySelector(".listing-name").textContent`, however how would i go about fetching all `listing-name` into an Array?

**DOM Structure**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="active-listings">
        <section class="listing">
            <div class="listing-info">
                <h3 class="listing-name">Listing 1</h3>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="listing">
            <div class="listing-info">
                <h3 class="listing-name">Listing 2</h3>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am new to Javascript so not entirely familiar with the correct syntax. However am i right in assuming i'd need to loop all the sections within the `active-listings` div and then obtain the `listing-name` that way?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is what you are after. It returns all elements matching the selector.

Comment: Thank you, don't know how i missed this. Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Took some time, I was on my way from work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the method you are looking for, which is available on all elements having `querySelector` as an available method, is `querySelectorAll`. Whereas `querySelector` returns the first element that matches, `querySelectorAll` matches **any** and returns them as an array.

As a result, in your example, if you were to get all the `active-listings` to get a sub-element's inner text, you'd simply do it this way (ES6):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".active-listings .listing-name").forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element.innerText);
  });
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active-listings">
    <h3 class="listing-name">Test</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="active-listings">
    <h3 class="listing-name">Test</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="active-listings">
    <h3 class="listing-name">Test</h3>
  </li>
    <li class="active-listings">
    <h3 class="listing-name">Test</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If your nesting is more complex, or if you need to do additional processing, merely selecting `active-listings` is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `querySelectorAll` : [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

The `querySelectorAll()` method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.

The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

```
 var matches = document.querySelectorAll("some_selector");
 //then you can access the matched selector with `matches`
```